# How to find the outliers from the data set and plot using Z score

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, statistics, seaborn, outliers

Data set is below

```
store id,revenue ,profit
101,779183,281257
101,144829,838451
101,766465,757565
101,353297,261071
101,1615461,275760
102,246731,949229
102,951518,301016
102,444669,430583
```

Code is below

```
import pandas as pd
dummies1 = dummies[['storeid', 'revenue', 'profit']]
cols = list(dummies1.columns)
cols.remove('storeid')
dummies1[cols]
# code to find the z score
for col in cols:
    col_zscore = col + '_zscore'
    dummies1[col_zscore] = (dummies1[col] - dummies1[col].mean())/dummies1[col].std(ddof=0)
```

Here I need to scatter-plot, box plot with outliers, How to to do

How to find the outliers is below ?

let say `threshold is 3` means np.abs(z_score) > threshold will consider as outlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing the data based on the z-score will you you the data to plot.  If you just want to find where one variable is an outlier you can do (for example):

```
THRESHOLD = 1.5 #nothing > 3 in your example

to_plot = dummies1[(np.abs(dummies1['revenue_zscore']) > THRESHOLD)]
```

Or if either column can be an outlier, you can do:

```
to_plot = dummies1[(np.abs(dummies1['revenue_zscore']) > THRESHOLD) | 
                   (np.abs(dummies1['profit_zscore']) > THRESHOLD)]
```

You weren't very specific about the plot, but here's an example taking advantage of this (using `~` to reverse the detection of outliers for normal points):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))
non_outliers = dummies1[~((np.abs(dummies1['revenue_zscore']) > THRESHOLD) | 
                        (np.abs(dummies1['profit_zscore']) > THRESHOLD))]
outliers = dummies1[((np.abs(dummies1['revenue_zscore']) > THRESHOLD) | 
                    (np.abs(dummies1['profit_zscore']) > THRESHOLD))]

ax.scatter(non_outliers['revenue'],non_outliers['profit'])
ax.scatter(outliers['revenue'],outliers['profit'], color='red', marker='x')
ax.set_ylabel('Profit')
ax.set_xlabel('Revenue')
```

[image]

Comment: can we do box plot, Storeid vs Revenue, StoreId vs Profit

Comment: You should try it yourself and post again here (or in a new question) if you run into issues.  Look into [`boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html), but note that this has its own way of graphing outliers.  If you do so you can graph your own outliers as using `scatter`

Comment: Not good with Plotting that is why ask. Any way thanks for answering I will check if run into issue i wil ask the question. THanks again