# Estimation Based Time Series Outlier Detection

Tags: python, time-series, multi-level

The data looks like:

[image]

- This is a **time series minute** data.
- In the data we have multiple **days**, **mkt**(market), **channel**.
- Each **channel** has a viewing(refer to **value** column) for whole day(refer to **day_part** column).
- If there is no vieving for that minute the value will be 0.
- **day_part** contains minute for whole day(24 hours).
- So for each date, each mkt, each channel we have 1440 rows.
  for example: what_date = 20230106 and day_part 0200-0201 is 1st January 2023 02:00:00 PM - 1st January 2023 02:00:59 PM

**Objective:** To find **outlier** for each date, market, channel. So my x-axis will be **day_part** and y axis will be **value**.

**Questions:**

- Does changing the frequency of data helps? Because I would like to know the minute of the anomaly (if any in the whole day).
- Best way to deal with this multi level time series data to get the outlier. Is there any Python library that can help me with this?

Comment: Can you check this link; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278775/how-to-find-the-outliers-from-the-data-set-and-plot-using-z-score . I might be wrong but multivariate outlier detection is just the sum of `z` scores on a number of variables. Your time range is 2 hours and you want to know when the anomaly happened in terms of minutes. I'd try to find the anomaly in the `day_part` and then sift through the 1 hour data. By the way, `0200-0201` is such a mind bending way to represent a 1 hour window, Is there a reason for this lol?

Comment: Sorry its a minute data not hour. 0200-0201 is 2:00 - 2:01. 0201-0202 is 2:01-2:02.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now! I would combine `what_date` and `day_part` into a UNIX timestamp, use that as `x` and `value` as `y` for each `channel`. That way you can spot outliers visually easily. Apply `z` score function on that data as well and I think you're good to go. I'm not entirely sure how `mkt` is related to this problem. Could you provide some sample data so I could tinker with it?

Comment: How many samples do you have for a same (date, market, channel). Something like `print(df.value_counts(['what_date', 'mkt', 'channel']).div(1440).mean())`? (Do you use `pandas`?)

Comment: @doneforaiur The data has 5 markets  and for each market there are different channels. For example mkt =1 can have 100 channels, mkt= 2 can have 120 channels in a single day.

Comment: @Corralien yes I do. For each date , mkt there are multiple channels. For instance date = 20230101 , mkt=1 has 50 channels, mkt = 2 has 80 channels.

Comment: So what your are looking for is to find outliers for each (date, mkt) and not (date, market, channel)? In other words, if you consider (date=20230101, mkt=1) as a cluster, you can have 50 different time series. And you want to remove some of them.

Comment: I want to find outliers for each (date, market, channel).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how you can find any outliers for a same (date, market, channel) if you have 1440 values for each one. It doesn't make sense (for me) to keep only a part of your values (for example from 8am to 6pm because everything else is outside the range). Anyway if you want to do that, you have to ensure your data follow a normal distribution.

Comment: @Corralien 
For example we have time series for X number of days so I would like to find outlier for all the markets, channels for each day if there is any.

Comment: To start with I am thinking on for exponential moving averages or Isolation Forest.